# Unable to retrieve BFILE data from Linux server(Oracle DB) in Java

Tags: java, linux, oracle

I am trying to retrieve Images from Oracle DB which is installed on Linux server. I have opened connection to Oracle DB and have written below code to read image file:

```
String sqlQuery2 = "SELECT DOC_CONTENT FROM GES_TRV_ASSIST_VISA_IMG_INTF_V T WHERE   T.TRV_REQ_NUM = ?";
pst2 = DBHelper.getPrepareStatement(sqlQuery2, "getPDFStreamData", con);
pst2.setInt(1, 1181241);
rs2 = DBHelper.executeQueryUsingPrepareStatement(pst2, "getPDFStreamData");
BufferedInputStream input = null;
while(rs2.next()){
    bfile = ((OracleResultSet)rs2).getBFILE (1);    
}
System.out.println("getDirAlias() = " + bfile.getDirAlias());
System.out.println("getName() = " + bfile.getName());
System.out.println("fileExists() = " + bfile.fileExists()); //Throwing exception here
System.out.println("isFileOpen() = " + bfile.isFileOpen());

// now open the bfile to get the data
bfile.openFile();

// get the BFILE data as a binary stream
InputStream in = bfile.getBinaryStream();
int length;

// read the bfile data in 6-byte chunks
byte[] buf = new byte[6];
while ((length = in.read(buf)) != -1)
{
    // append and display the bfile data in 6-byte chunks
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(length);
    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
        sb.append( (char)buf[i] );
```

I am able to retrieve directory name and file name however It is throwing exception at `bfile.fileExists()` by saying file does't exist, but file is there in the mentioned path. I have followed many blogs and tutorials but no result. My doubt here is I have access to Oracle DB is that enough? or Do I need access for files directory also??

I have attached my oracle table image for better understanding. Can some one suggest me how to retrieve BFILE data from oracle DB?

[image: table schema]

Comment: What exception is thrown? Please add the full stack trace to your question.

Comment: This code is strange: `while (rs2.next()) { bfile = ((OracleResultSet)rs2).getBFILE (1); }`. You progress beyond the last row of the result set and then access the BFILE that's from a previous row.

Comment: //PFB Stack trace java.sql.SQLException: ORA-22285: non-existent directory or file for FILEEXISTS operation

 at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
 at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTIoer.processError(TTIoer.java:289)
 at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.v8TTILob.receiveReply(v8TTILob.java:989)
 at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.v8TTIBfile.doesExist(v8TTIBfile.java:262)
 at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.fileExists(TTC7Protocol.java:2869)
 at oracle.sql.LobDBAccessImpl.fileExists(LobDBAccessImpl.java:1060)
 at oracle.sql.BFILE.fileExists(BFILE.java:502)

Answer (score 0):

In order to successfully create a BFILE in Oracle, you use symbolic directory names:

```
create or replace directory DOC_CONTENT_DIR as '/home/storage/docs';
grant read, write on DOC_CONTENT_DIR to user1;
insert into GES_TRV_ASSIST_VISA_IMG_INTF_V values(1, 3, 'US', BFILENAME('DOC_CONTENT_DIR', 'image.jpeg'), 'image.jpeg');
commit;
```

In addition to the grant in Oracle, the oracle user will also need the appropriate access permission on operation system level:

```
chown oracle /home/storage/docs
```

Furthermore, you need to fix this. It's wrong:

```
while(rs2.next()){
   bfile = ((OracleResultSet)rs2).getBFILE (1);    
}
```

If you expect a single row in the result, just write:

```
rs2.next();
bfile = ((OracleResultSet)rs2).getBFILE (1);
```

If that doesn't help, please add the output of your program (before the crash) to your question.

Comment: I may get OS access permissions in few days, once I get access I will check it and let you know. If I face any issues I will post my output here.